# Spring ThreadLocalTargetSource - does this have memory leaks?

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, thread-local

I intend to use Spring's `ThreadLocalTargetSource` for accessing the user context for my web app and web services application.

I have browsed through the net for sometime now and all I see are scary results about the memory leaks. I see that the `ThreadLocalTargetSource` implementation already has a `destroy` method that cleans up and nullifies the threadlocal object. I believe all this is good. Then why do we get memory leaks when Spring is handling it in the right way? Is there anything that we need to do for this explicitly?

Comment: Can you post some links to the scary results you mention?

Comment: Thanks Duncan, well this one below mentions about the evils of ThreadLocal. Since spring's threadlocaltarget is built over threadlocal, I was skeptical if this might cause issues in my project? Better safe than late...
http://blog.igorminar.com/2009/03/identifying-threadlocal-memory-leaks-in.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not a big harm to use, but have to be bit careful.

As the API docs suggest, every thread will have its copy of the target and also there might be few thread-bound objects which might be in memory till application actually shuts down.

The API statements just suggests this class have to be used with bit of extra care, though string provides destroy method make the object available for GC. Otherwise, it is very good to use.

Unset the object for every request cycle if you want to use ThreadLocal.

Please refer to below links to a blog and API doc

http://tigrou.nl/2009/05/09/springs-threadlocaltargetsource/

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/aop/target/ThreadLocalTargetSource.html

Comment: Thanks Abhijith, what do you mean by **make the object available for GC**, SPRING is exactly doing that in the destroy method isn't it?  Please let me know on this, may be am misunderstanding you here.

Comment: This is my code , (Is this all good or do we need anything else to be included?)  

`ThreadLocalTargetSource t= (ThreadLocalTargetSource)appCtx.getBean("threadLocal");  
   ReqContext reqContext = (ReqContext)target.getTarget();     
UserContext usrholder = reqContext.getUserContext();  
usrholder.setAppId("Tset");  `

Comment: I meant the same, Spring nullifies the threadpool and its associated objects and nullified objects are cleared by GC.

Comment: So, we are good to go with the above code without any customized handling right?

Comment: One quick query tagged to this, if i need to monitor the threadlocal objects. is there a way to do that via the MAT tool(Eclipse - Memory Analyzer tool) ?